# Testing helpers functions with karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

In angular, I have this factory

```
function helperFunction(user){
  // more code
  return user;
}

angular.module('factories', [])
.factory('Users', function() {
  var users = [];
  return {
    add: function(user) {
      user = helperFunction(user);
      users.push(user);
    },
    all: function(){
      return users;
    }
  };
});
```

with karma, I can test the factory, similar to

```
describe('factories', function() {

  beforeEach(module('factories'));

  var users;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_Users_) {
    users = _Users_;
  }));

  it('test over add function', function(){
    users.add({name:'name'});
    // ...
  });

  });
});
```

how I can test the `helperFunction` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for what you are going to test because your "add" function doesn't return any value, so it can't be consumed by either a controller or another service.

Here are some resources that could be useful:

- [Testing service only](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/12/unit-testing-services-in-angularjs-for-fun-and-for-profit/)
- [Testing service used by a controller](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/testing-services.html)

For your case, just include the helper function in your "Users" service or a "Helpers" service as you can't test a function that has no relate to any scope or service. But I suppose there is no need to test it here because the "add" functionality always means you just add something, and you want to test critical parts of your app.

Comment: add function is only add a value, other functions can return values. now I edit the example with a return function.

Comment: based on your edit, you should call the "add" function, then verify the output of the "all" function. if you insist on testing the helper one, you should add it beside the two above as my suggestion.